Use @Model class on View without saving it to context first
Can I use a SwiftData @Model class without inserting it into the context, e.g. for a temporary draft feature?
@Model
final class Customer {
    var id: UUID
    var dateChanged: Date
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \CustomerBasic.customer) var basic: CustomerBasic
}

@Model
final class CustomerBasic {
    var id: UUID
    var dateChanged: Date
    var customer: Customer?
    var registered: Bool
}

I create a new Customer via:
class FreshData {
    func newCustomer() -> Customer {            
        let customerBasic: CustomerBasic = CustomerBasic(id: UUID(), dateChanged: Date(), registered: false)
        let customer: Customer = Customer(id: UUID(), dateChanged: Date(), basic: customerBasic)

        return customer
    }
}

I then pass it to a view on which the app user can create a new customer:
NavigationLink(value: NavCustomerEditView(customer: FreshData().newCustomer(), caller: .new), label: {
                    Label("addString", systemImage: "plus")
                })

The app crashes when trying to compute the navTitle:
struct CustomerEditView: View {
    
    @State var customer: Customer
    var caller: Caller
    
    var navTitle: String {
        var value: String = String(localized: "customerNewString")
        
        if caller == .new {
            value = customer.basic.id.uuidString
        }
        
        return value
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
        }
        .navigationTitle(navTitle)
    }
}

I don't understand why I can successfully access the property customer.id but not property customer.basic.id. Accessing customer.basic.id crashes:
get {
    _$observationRegistrar.access(self, keyPath: \.basic)
    return self.getValue(forKey: \.basic) <-- Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT
}

I suppose I can fix this by saving both Customer and CustomerBasic to context. However, I don't want to delete the Customer object again if the user chooses not to save this new customer from a save button on the CustomerEditView.
A workaround would be to create an identical Customer and CustomerBasic struct with which I work on the CustomerEditView and on save transform it to the @Model Customer and CustomerBasic class and save it to context.
This seems like an unnecessary doubling of code.
Question 1: Why can I successfully access the property customer.id but not the property customer.basic.id?
Question 2: Is there any way I can use the @Model classes on CustomerEditView without saving them to context first?
Question 3: Is creating an identical struct the best solution if question 2 is impossible?

You can use model objects without inserting them but it’s the relationship that is the issue here. I don’t know if it’s a bug but you can’t access it without inserting the objects into a ModelContext. If this is just a temporary thing then maybe treat them as two different objects without setting the relationship property
